# aura:storage use

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My use case is the following: Some of my components must have working action.setStorable ( as the result of their server actions may always be the same , like list of picklist values, so no need to interrogate the server each time )

How can I initialize correctly aura Storage so the cache in the following code is really taken in account ?

```
initItemsFromSObjectFieldHlp : function(component) {
    var SObjectField = component.get('v.sObjectField');
    var action = component.get("c.listPickListValuesApex");
    action.setParams({'sObjectField': SObjectField }); 
    action.setStorable(); // result is stored in aura cache coz it'll always be the same
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var items = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.items',items);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);           
}
```

I struggle with documentation to use aura:storage ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_auraStorage_init.htm )
It says *Use auraStorage:init to initialize storage in your **app**’s template for caching server-side action response values.* , but just after the example is with a component ...

If i copy-paste the doc example in a component CmpInitStorage that I include in my main component, i see the following error :

```
<aura:component isTemplate="true" extends="aura:template">
    <aura:set attribute="auraPreInitBlock">
        <!-- Note that the maxSize attribute in auraStorage:init is in KB -->
        <auraStorage:init name="actions" persistent="false" secure="false"
         maxSize="1024" />
    </aura:set>
</aura:component>
```

included with

```
<c:CmpInitStorage />
```

error triggered :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

I also tried to add directly in my component or in my main .app but it doesn't work neither

```
<aura:set attribute="auraPreInitBlock">
    <!-- Note that the maxSize attribute in auraStorage:init is in KB -->
    <auraStorage:init name="actions" persistent="false" secure="false"
     maxSize="1024" />
</aura:set>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<aura:component isTemplate="true"/>` means the "component" is a template for an app. Check out this documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_template_overview.htm

You need to add the `template="c:CmpInitStorage"` attribute to your app's `<aura:application>` tag.

Comment: Ok ... a component is a template for an application ... didn't get this one :)

Comment: Now i have a new problem, it works well with a standalone app, but in a app included by a VF page, it generates error Uncaught TypeError: $A.$clientService$.$initHost$ is not a function throws at https://xxxxxxx-developer-edition.eu11.force.com/distributor/auraFW/javascript/-Nl7t7IjS5oiqOIuVwZRSw/aura_proddebug.js:17270:24 and nothing works :/ Will post a new question

Comment: It's http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147270/aurastorage-crashing-when-used-in-a-ltngoutapp, right?

Comment: yes, it seems to be a SFDC bug :/

Comment: I'm a Software Architect at Salesforce. We already have a work item internally tracking this and it's being investigated. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Saw a message from Doug Chasman, thanks for your reactivity :) While u're here, if u could take a look at this one which is really blocking me but doesn't seem to bother a lot of people .... :( --> http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146235/handler-change-not-working-with-attribute-updated-inside-auraiteration