# Aura:storage crashing when used in a ltng:outApp

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to use aura storage in an app included from a VF page, but I have the following error.
Same code works well for a standalone .app

Uncaught TypeError: $A.$clientService$.$initHost$ is not a function throws at  https://xxxxxxx-developer-edition.eu11.force.com/distributor/auraFW/javascript/-Nl7t7IjS5oiqOIuVwZRSw/aura_proddebug.js:17270:24

Sample app code :

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" 
                  extends="ltng:outApp" 
                  description="Only used for visualforce page javascript inclusion of main big component">
                  template="c:TemplateAppForStorage"
    <aura:dependency resource="c:MyMainBigComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

TemplateAppForStorage:

```
<aura:component isTemplate="true" extends="aura:template" description="App template to initialize storage">
    <aura:set attribute="auraPreInitBlock">
        <!-- Note that the maxSize attribute in auraStorage:init is in KB -->
        <auraStorage:init name="actions" 
                          persistent="false" 
                          secure="true"
                          maxSize="2048" />
    </aura:set>
</aura:component>
```

Sample of including vf page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"
       cache="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false"> 

    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightningvfDIV" style="min-height: 100% !important;display:block;"/>

    <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:MyAppForVfPage", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:MyMainBigComponent", 
                                           {},
                                           "lightningvfDIV",
                                           function(cmp) {
                                              console.log('Page includer initialized'); 
                                           });
            });  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is specific to ltng:outApp's template not providing the environment that auraStorage:init is expecting.

I have opened bug **W-3451404** to track this if you wan to reference this in any communications with Salesforce support.

Comment: I see too many bugs to bother SF support with them each time, I fully trust u to take them in account, many thanks for your reactivity Doug :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's any help Nicolas if you change the init to be

```
<auraStorage:init name="actions" 
                          persistent="true" 
                          secure="false"
                          maxSize="2048" />
```

Then the error is removed.  I.e. I changed the persistent and secure values.  The persistent setting doesn't seem to work for me; ie if I refresh the page then it seems to skip the cache so that currently will not be a problem.  However the cached data will be insecure which might be a bigger issue for you.

Comment: It doesn't trigger the inital crash but, it triggered ... unavailability of $Resource references (err 503 when getting bootstrap.css !) :/

And in the console I still see : "Uncaught error in $A.run() [$A.$clientService$.$initHost$ is not a function]"

So i'll wait for Doug's fix :)