# aura storage without template component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

My user case needs to dynamically create tokens for the logging user. It looks a perfect case for aura storage to store the token results from the server action. From the [answer of the question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147247/aurastorage-use), it looks the auraStorage is only applicable for template component. Since I need use my component in Lightning communities, there would be no need (and/or no way?) to define a lightning app. Is there a way to utilize auraStorage without template component?

Answer (score 0):

The Aura Storage Service only supports caching of serverside actions:

> Server-side actions storage is the only currently supported type of storage. Storage for server-side actions caches action response values. The storage name must be actions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/storage_init.htm

Within Communities and the Lightning Experience, the aura storage is already initialized for you and you can just used cached actions directly.

Stored/Cached actions are documented in depth here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_storable_actions.htm

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for the confirmation, Christian!

Comment: hm..., not sure what's wrong with it. I used action.setStorable() in the javascript controller, with ** "defaultAutoRefreshInterval": "1800"  and            "defaultExpiration": "1800"**, it did not help. I still saw the Apex controller being called each time.  Anyone has working sample to share?

Comment: A storable action will still hit the server in most cases. However, it will return an initial stored value and then hit your callback again with the fresh result.

Comment: yeah, that's what I observed. Actually the behavior of storable action is a perfect approach for my case. Thanks again for the explanation and confirmation!