# In lightning components, How to check if input value really changed?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

My goal is to check if the user really changed the value in the input field.

In visualforce, I do this by storing the old value in HTML5 data attributes and onchange event compare the old value with the new value to see if it really changed:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!oppObj.field1__c}"
                 html-data-oldValue="{!oppObj.field1__c}">
</apex:inputField
```

But I am confused as how to do the same in lightning components as these are not supporting html5 data attributes. I have code something like this and it is not taking html5 data attributes.

```
<ui:inputNumber aura:id="someFld" 
                class="slds-input" 
                value="{!oppObj.field1__c}"
                change="{!c.fieldChanged}">
</ui:inputNumber>
```

Any help on this?

**EDIT:**

I have ui:inputNumber inside the aura:iteration tag, so it is like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.oppList}"
                var="oppObj"
                indexVar="i">
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="{!i + '_someFld'}" 
                    class="slds-input" 
                    value="{!oppObj.field1__c}">
    </ui:inputNumber>
</aura:iteration>
```

As suggested, I am trying to define `<aura:handler name="change"../>` inside `aura:iteration` but it throws this error :

> Failed to save undefined: markup://c:TestComponent:231,67:
>   Invalid attribute "name": Source

Answer (score 2):

You could use a handler for that.

Add this to your component:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.valueChanged}"/>
```

`v.value` =  aura:attribute

`c.valueChanged` = method in your lightning controller

Then your `ui:input` would be like so:

```
<ui:inputNumber aura:id="someFld" 
            class="slds-input" 
            value="{!v.value}"
            change="{c.valueChanged}">
</ui:inputNumber>
```

Example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. One more question, my `<ui:inputNumber>` component is inside the `<aura:iteration>` tag so not sure how to define `<aura:handler>` for this. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: It should work for a value in `<aura:iteration>`. ---- 

You could use `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.ListItem.SomeVal}" action=" {!c.valueChanged}"/>` as mentioned in this similar post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146235/handler-change-not-working-with-attribute-updated-inside-auraiteration

Comment: @javanoob Please update the question by adding info that inputNumber is inside aura:iteration. It's an important information which you should have to include in the first place.

Comment: @Praveen, Agree with that. I updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. "aura:valueChange" event fires when value changes.
2. The "aura:valueChange" event is handled by a client-side controller. A component can have multiple `<aura:handler name="change">`

   tags to detect changes to different attributes.

Example:

Component:

```
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myBool}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>
     <aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="someFld" 
                class="slds-input" 
                value="3"
                change="{!c.fieldChanged}">
</ui:inputNumber>
```

Controller:

```
({
     handleValueChange : function (component, event, helper) {
        // handle value change
        console.log("old value: " + event.getParam("oldValue"));
        console.log("current value: " + event.getParam("value"));
    },
     fieldChanged : function (component, event, helper) {
      component.set("v.myBool", false);
    }

})
```